# Rails - escaping URL parameters in a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I've got a rails application with a route:

```
put /soa/orders/:order_id => 'soa/orders#update'
```

The snag I have hit is that `:order_id` is a string, not an integer, and typically of a format such as `ABC - 001`.  Since spaces are not valid in a URL, the order_id is URL escaped to `ABC+-+001`.

I was expecting Rails to automatically unescape this parameter, the same way it would do with other parameters, but it does not appear to.  I have got it working, by manually unescaping it, but I wanted to check if anyone knows, is this intended behaviour or does it only do what I'm seeing in specific circumstances?

Comment: Hm, I'm surprised it's not being escaped as `ABC%20-%20001`, which would "auto escape" properly. How, and where specifically, are the parameters being escaped to begin with?

Comment: Could be onto something there.  It's an API with requests made by an external system which escapes the parameters when required.  I need to double check what escaping it does/should use!

Comment: Maybe the API is replacing spaces with plus signs, instead of escaping the spaces. Perhaps it's a convention of the API to do it this way rather than try to encode the parameters "as is".

Comment: Looks like a bug in the external application - plus signs are allowed instead of %20, but only in the query string section.  I hadn't been aware of that distinction, and evidently neither is the other application (along with quite a number of other systems...).